# Labor pains are some of the worst kinds of the pains

Tags: sentence-request

How one should say a particular type of pain lie the labor pain is one of the most severe ones that a person / woman can experience in their lives?

I was wondering if my following sentences work in this situation:

> - Labor pains are some of the worst kinds of the pains.
> - Labor pains are one of the worst kinds of the pains.

If not, then what shall I say?

Comment: You had it almost right in your description: "labor pain is one of the most severe a woman can experience in her life"

Comment: Your question would be better (and on-topic) if you stated what appears to be the actual issue (*some of* vs. *one of*), along with some research on these terms. As written this is just proofreading.

Comment: @user3169 I never ever want someone to proofread my sentences. Actually I want to make sure if a concept's equivalent in English (especially AmE) is natural or there is a gap there. This is what I am looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close.

I think maybe it might be worth rephrasing.

> One of the worst kinds of pain is caused by labor.

Although, if you want to stay with the same phrasing, you just need to make a few adjustments

> Labor pain is one of the worst kinds of pain.

or

> Labor pains are one of the worst kinds of pain.

Answer (score 1):

Labor pains are among the worst kinds of pain.

Labor pains are among the worst pains.

Compare *[among the worst forms of child labor](https://books.google.com/books?id=1VMIZ-2zSSUC&pg=PA45&dq=%22among%20the%20worst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq88KAqerRAhWlx4MKHSTBCe8Q6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22among%20the%20worst%22&f=false)*.